# Remove the form close button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need a form without buttons, but with Text and icon;
So far, I managed to get it except the close "X" button;
Is there a way to remove it?
My code is below,

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Text = "Form with Icon and Text, but NO Buttons"
        Me.Icon = New Icon("c:\test.ico")
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.MinimizeBox = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can set the form `Controlbox` property to false to remove the close button, but you will also lose the icon. There's no other way to do it natively.

Comment: Thanks Blue Dog; I knew that; That is why I mentioned that I want to keep Text and Icon.

Comment: Ah, how about keeping the close button, but just disabling its function? You can do this by putting `e.Cancel = True` in the form closing event.

Comment: hmmmm; mainly, I want to do it for aesthetic reason, not just to prevent user from closing it.

Comment: I see. There are a few code examples on the web that will 'grey' it out, but I don't think it's possible to remove it altogether through code.

Comment: There is no option to keep the icon and remove the min/max/close buttons.  These kind of aesthetics require you to draw the caption yourself.  Starting point is a borderless window and a bunch of really gritty code to get the lost features back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround this by one of the following (two involves custom drawing on the title bar):

1. Disable the close button and custom draw on the title bar to hide it
2. Remove the close button and draw the icon on the title bar

check this link for custom title bar drawing : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks... Seems using  custom title bar drawing is the only solution. Much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide it using `Me.ControlBox=false;` in code or in properties change the 
**ControlBox** option to **false**

Comment: Thanks Mumin Asaad; this is same answer as Blue Dog above; I will lose the icon.

Comment: i didn't see the comments :)

Comment: That's also C#, OP is using VB. ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog LoL 100% true

Comment: @TheBlueDog just remove `;` and it's not C# anymore.

Comment: @Hoh: Hence the wink at the end of my comment.